# How can I save values with user.id to Database - Django

Tags: python, django

I want to save the values that users enter into the repository. But if the user has already entered a value, I want it to update.

It's saving the data right now. But it cannot update.

I' am use Django

forms.py

```
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('apikey', 'apivalue', 'apisupplier')
```

views.py

```
def user_set_api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        current_user = request.user
        user_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        user_id = current_user.id
        print('UserId:', user_id)
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_id:
            user_form.save(request.user)
            print('User: ', user, 'Userformid:', UserProfileInfo(['user_id']))
        else:
            print(user_form)
    else:
        keysvalue = UserProfileInfoForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html',
                  {'apisupplier': UserProfileInfo})
```

models.py

````
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    apisupplier = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default="null")
    apikey = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default="null")
    apivalue = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default="null")

    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.user} {0.apikey} {0.apivalue} {0.apisupplier}'
        return template.format(self)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are passing the user id to form.save(). You need to pass the user object to the form instantiation:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    user_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if user_form.is_valid()
        user_form.save()
        ...
else:
    user_form = UserProfileInfoForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, 'form.html',
              {'apisupplier': UserProfileInfo, "user_form": user_form})
```

Comment: Hello Daniel. Thanks for your answer. But It's not working. Error message: The view userapp.views.user_set_api didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. I save another database for user's apikey, apisupplier and apivalue.

Comment: That last line was indented too far, try it now.

Comment: It's not save to db. And not render form.html page